# i cannot find version of ngx-Permission compatible with my Project @angular/core 5.2.8

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot find the correct version of ngx-permission compatible with my project @angular/core 5.2.8 .
I install many versions @0.1.0  @0.1.1 @0.2.0  @ngxpermissions 4.1.0 (for Angular 5) but in vain.

Comment: what about latest version ```npm i ngx-permissions``` and whats vain?

Comment: Hi

Following https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions/issues/59 

Description:

ngx-permission@5.0 version is compatible with Angular 6

ngx-permission@4.1 version is compatible with Angular 5

Basically 4.1 is compatible with a5.x.y, what error you got ?in npm install or in the compilation | serve ?